# Android studio 2.2.2 Cmake add prebuild FFmpeg 3.2 error

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am use the Android Studio 2.2.2 version on Windows and cmake function try to add prebuild FFmpeg 3.2 version on mac.

I also search many question on here but still got this error message

```
    Error:error: 'libs/armeabi/lib/libavformat-57.so',needed by '../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi/libnative-lib.so',missing and no known rule to make it
```

I did a project with include C++ support and the ffmpeg prebuild lib and include is place

`C:\Users\fw\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\app\libs\armeabi`.

I build this project got error everytimes.

Does any can help with this and also tell me why should I do.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the whole issue, are you saying that you have built FFmpeg 3.2 on Mac and you're trying to use that binary in your Android app?

Comment: Yes, I build the whole project then error message show like that.